# Filter pandas DataFrame using a column of np arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas dataframe with a column containing arrays. I want to filter my df based on values of the column with arrays. For example, for the `df`

```
        subject                                           position  current_choice    inpt
837  ash  [0.0, 0.005792712956593603, 0.0207826510381976...            -1.0  [-0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]
838  zad  [0.0, -0.00044640180445325853, -0.000892803608...             1.0    [1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
839  pop  [0.0, 5.2698260765019904e-05, 0.00010539652153...             1.0   [0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]
840  syc  [0.0, 0.0031267642423531117, 0.014658282457501...             1.0      [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
841  ash  [0.0, -0.00013353844781401902, -0.000267076895...            -1.0   [-0.125, 1.0, 1.0]
```

I want to select `df[df['inpt']==[0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]]`. But I get the error

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (95994,), (3,))
```

Is there a way around it?

Also, how can we find unique rows in such a column?

Comment: Try using `Lamda ` function  to compare Each Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a vectorial comparison:

```
out = df[np.isclose(np.vstack(df['inpt']), [0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
  subject                                         position  current_choice                inpt
2     pop  [0.0, 5.2698260765019904e-05, 0.00010539652153]             1.0  [0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: thank you. can you also answer the last part of the question, regarding the unique entries in a df column of arrays

Comment: @jaweria do you mean `np.unique(np.vstack(df['inpt']), axis=0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Filtering the DataFrame based on the values in the 'inpt' column, you can use the apply method along with a lambda function to compare each element in the 'inpt' column individually with the target array. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd

# Your DataFrame
data = {'subject': ['ash', 'zad', 'pop', 'syc', 'ash'],
        'position': [[0.0, 0.005792712956593603, 0.0207826510381976], [0.0, -0.00044640180445325853, -0.000892803608], [0.0, 5.2698260765019904e-05, 0.00010539652153], [0.0, 0.0031267642423531117, 0.0146582824575], [0.0, -0.00013353844781401902, -0.000267076895]],
        'current_choice': [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0],
        'inpt': [[-0.0625, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, -1.0, -1.0], [0.0625, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [-0.125, 1.0, 1.0]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

target_array = [0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]

filtered_df = df[df['inpt'].apply(lambda x: x == target_array)]

print(filtered_df)
```

resulted Output:

[image]

If the `inpt` is of numpy array, change the target to numpy array and try comparing

```
target_array = np.array([0.0625, 1.0, 1.0])  # Convert target_array to a NumPy array

df['inpt'] = df['inpt'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

filtered_df = df[df['inpt'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, target_array))]
```

Comment: I get the following error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: @jaweria can you give specific line where you are getting the error in the above script!

Comment: I think the error arises because in my code each row df['inpt'] is an np array whereas in your code, it is a list

Comment: stack overflow won't allow me to post the whole traceback in the comments

Comment: try changing the `target_array = np.array([0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]) `

Comment: `filtered_df = df[df['inpt'].apply(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, target_array))]` works. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mozway's answer, i'll try to explain why the error is triggered. But first, here my quick workaround : Go with tuples in both sides (`left`, `right`) of the comparison or use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

```
>>> df[df["inpt"].apply(tuple) == (0.0625, 1.0, 1.0)]

>>> df[df["inpt"].isin([[0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]])] #equivalent

    subject             position  current_choice                inpt
839     pop  [0.0, 5.26982607...          1.0000  [0.0625, 1.0, 1.0]
```

That's because when you perform a comparison between a Series and another object, [`comparison_ops`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py#L290) is invoked behind the scenes. And this one, doesn't treat `list`s as the other types (a `tuple` in particular).

So, at the end (*see below*), if it turns out to be a `list`, it must have the same length as the Series and this way each element will be compared to its corresponding one in the other side `[Series.element1 <> list.element1, ...]`. Otherwise, the `ValueError` is raised.

```
def comparison_op(left: ArrayLike, right: Any, op) -> ArrayLike:
    """
    Evaluate a comparison operation `=`, `!=`, `>=`, `>`, `<=`, or `<`.
    ...
    """

    lvalues = ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike(left)
    rvalues = ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike(right)
    rvalues = lib.item_from_zerodim(rvalues)

    if isinstance(rvalues, list):
        # We don't catch tuple here bc we may be comparing e.g. MultiIndex
        #  to a tuple that represents a single entry, see test_compare_tuple_strs
        rvalues = np.asarray(rvalues)

    if isinstance(rvalues, (np.ndarray, ABCExtensionArray)):
        # TODO: make this treatment consistent across ops and classes.
        #  We are not catching all listlikes here (e.g. frozenset, tuple)
        #  The ambiguous case is object-dtype.  See GH#27803
        if len(lvalues) != len(rvalues):
            raise ValueError(
                "Lengths must match to compare", lvalues.shape, rvalues.shape
            )
```